# Why dependent template name accepted without keyword?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

I've written a template `entry_func`, which uses a template method `func` of a template class. In `entry_func`, to call `func`, I should use the keyword `template`. In the example, the line (1) doesn't compile and the line (2) does. So far ok.

However, if I change the line (1) a little and get the line (3), the line (3) compiles too, without the keyword `template`. Why? In my understanding, the change should not affect the need of the keyword.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class>
struct Impl {
  template<class T>
  static T func(T t) {
    static_assert(sizeof(T)>=0, "Shouldn't be instantiated.");
  }
};

template<>
struct Impl<std::is_pointer<int*>> {
  template<class T>
  static T func(T u) {
    return u;
  }
};

template<class T>
inline T entry_func(T u) {
//return Impl<std::is_pointer<T  >>::func<T>(u);          // (1) fail
//return Impl<std::is_pointer<T  >>::template func<T>(u); // (2) ok
  return Impl<std::is_pointer<int>>::func<T>(u);          // (3) ok???
}

int main() {}
```

g++ version 5.3.1, clang version 3.8.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Impl<std::is_pointer<int>>::func` in *(3)* is not a dependent name in `entry_func`.
Because of that, the fact that `func` is a template function can be easily resolved without the `template` keyword.
Note that in this case, you are using `T` to specialize `Impl<std::is_pointer<int>>::func` and not `Impl<std::is_pointer<int>>`, as you did in *(1)*/*(2)*. This is the key to read the differences between the two cases.